# Configuring a relationship that uses Table Splitting in EF Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to build my first Table Splitting in EF Core 2 using fluent configuration. 
 
I have two simple entities named `User` and `Customer` and I want use them in single table named "AppUsers". So I created a simple entity classes for both:

**User.cs**

```
public partial class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

And:

**Customer.cs**

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then I make changes to `MyDbContext` as:

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Customer).WithOne(c => c.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Customer>(e => e.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AppUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("AppUsers");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And then I created a migration using `Add-Migration "Simple_Test"` without errors. So I run `Update-Database` that worked fine without console error but when I trying to run app getting this error:

> The entity of 'User' is sharing the table 'AppUsers' with 'Customer', but there is no entity of this type with the same key value that has been marked as 'Added'

I cant understand this. I'm student just started learning about relationship configuration. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that each row in the database table now contains fields from two entities--one User and one Customer. This means that every time a User is created and saved, there must also be a Customer created and saved with the same Id, because the database row cannot hold only a User or only a Customer, it must have both.

I added Customer seed's in another method that's my fool. That must be in User seed's.
 `var user = new User();
 user.Customer = new Customer { Id = user.Id }`